# sql update row IF row in other table = value

Tags: mysql

I need a MySQL query that will set a row value to x IF the row value from another table = x

```
first table = `tblclients`

SET `status`='Closed'
IF
second table = `tblhosting`
AND `domainstatus`='Cancelled'
```

Comment: Is there a relationship between the tables? What is their structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join to tables in `UPDATE` statement. You can try something like this.

```
UPDATE tblCLients a 
          INNER JOIN tblHosting b
              on a.commonID = b.commonID     -- their relationship key
SET a.`Status` = IF(b.domainStatus = 'Cancelled', 'Closed', 'Open')
```